# Android: How to create a customized edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I am wondering if anybody can help me with designing an editText like the following:
[image]

Note the red vertical line meant to show the obligatory field.

Comment: Just add a view to the right of your EditText, set the width to 2dp, and the background to whatever color you want (android:color/red in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recreated what you are looking for through the layout and it may not be exactly what you are looking for. I gave it a try because I thought it looked pretty good.

This is how it looks when created
[image: EditText]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="#d2d2d2">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="#6d6d6d"/>

    <view
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use View instead of LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selector.

For example:

In res-->drawable folder create another xml file with name "custom_edittext.xml" and paste  below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_edittext_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_edittext_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Finally call custom_edittext.xml as background in your editText

```
<EditText
   ... 
   android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
   ...
/>
```